# How to configure ipyparallel over IPv6 with CJDNS

Tags: python, ipython, ipv6, ipython-parallel

I've been dabbling in **ipyparallel**, and I must give props to their team. Got it running on my local network, but the next step eluded my skills.

Can't get ipcontroller and ipengine to converse over a subnet of the Internet built on IPv6 with **cjdns**. Status update:
 - engine hosts are reachable via SSH and SCP, which has been the means
   I'm using to copy the JSON configuration file
 - automatically-generated JSON files come prepacked with local IPv4 addresses from under 192.168.*.*
 - usage of --ip or --url when generating JSON file with ipcontroller didn't fix this
 - directly changing local IPv4 addresses to their respective IPv6 counterparts was also a dud

ps: first post here :)

Thank you for reading!